# How many tables can a single SQL Server 2012 database hold?

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012

I am working on C# application to create tables dynamically in a database. What is the maximum number of tables that one single database can hold or best practice for the number of tables to have in a database? The tables are not related to each other.

Note: Database is set to auto grow. There will be no max size for that database.

Comment: The answer is in the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.110).aspx).  Essentially unlimited.  But, if the application has more than a few hundred dynamic tables, then my guess is that you should redesign the data architecture.

Comment: There was a question here just a few days ago along the lines of "Why does my program slow down after accessing thousands of tables?" Having a very large number of tables means that you are forced to deal with them programmatically. You are restricted in a number of ways - for example it is very difficult to query them all, or do a data fix to them all. It is usually better to use a single table with an extra column(s) for a key. Of course, that table could grow unreasonably large - it would depend on your situation and the data.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx):

Tables per database: **Limited by number of objects in a database**

Database objects include objects such as tables, views, stored procedures, user-defined functions, triggers, rules, defaults, and constraints. The sum of the number of all objects in a database cannot exceed **2,147,483,647**.